# Getting webcam to work in OpenCV 2.3 with Cygwin

Tags: opencv, cygwin, webcam

I have a problem trying to get a webcam in OpenCV 2.3 to work with Cygwin.  I have a Windows 7 64-bit system and I use Notepad++ and cygwin compilers to do my C++ programming. I have seen other posts with similar problems:

[Getting Webcam to work in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294491/getting-webcam-to-work-in-opencv)

[Can't access webcam with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749498/cant-access-webcam-with-opencv)

I first tried installing OpenCV via the Cygwin Ports.  This is rather easy to install, but alas I run into the webcam problem (always returns false when trying to find a device).  I have also attempted to build OpenCV and install manually using the command line flavor of CMake.  I tried adding the HAVE_VIDEOINPUT and HAVE_DSHOW flags, but no dice.  All my programs compile nicely and I have all the functionality of OpenCV aside for this webcam thing.

Has anyone successfully built OpenCV 2.3 on Cygwin with webcam working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that cygwin build of OpenCV will be able to access a webcam. At least it is not possible without hacking OpenCV cmake scripts. Under cygwin OpenCV build always follows the UNIX branch and videoinput/directshow is excluded from build.

Comment: I am going to accept this.  I ended up doing a work-around.  I built OpenCV in VS2010 and ported over my module for capturing webcam frames to a new project in VS.  Once I got that working I grabbed the resulting Visual Studio App executable and put it near my project in the cygwin folders (for easy access). Now, when I need to capture the webcam I can use this App and output the frame data down the line to my other OpenCV tools.