# OpenCV not initializing USB camera

Tags: c++, video, opencv

I am trying to capture video from a USB camera using OpenCV.

```
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap (-1);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
         cout << "Cam initialize failed";
    else cout << "Cam initialized";

    return 0;
}
```

It is failing to initialize the camera. cap.isOpened() is returning zero.

The same program, with same version of OpenCV and the same USB camera,  is correctly running in my friend's machine. I am running [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) 16. The camera is properly working in another application (for example, [Cheese](http://blekko.com/ws/?q=site%3Aen.wikipedia.org%20Cheese%20software)).

I did some searching in Google and Stack Overflow. But no useful help.
Any idea?

Comment: Your camera works in another application?

Comment: Have you read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749498/cant-access-webcam-with-opencv

Comment: @vfcosta As I mentioned earlier, the camera is working fine with other applications. I used it in Cheese,Kamoso and vlc.

Comment: @james from the link you have given, it seems its problem in highgui. But the solution or solution hint given there was for Windows. I am running linux fedora 16. I do not know where to find the appropriate preprocessor  to be included.

Comment: @brainbarshan, I'm not sure how to include Preprocesser Definitions in linux but you can simply add 
#define HAVE_VIDEOINPUT 
#define HAVE_DSHOW
in an appropriate global header file (try modifying the existing opencv header file) and try recompiling the highgui lib.
btw, are you using the latest OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

Try running your program as root. You may not have permission, and opencv doesn't tell you if thats the reason cap.isOpened() failed.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) says that the `VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int device)` accepts

> device: id of the opened video capturing device (i.e. a camera index). If there is a single camera connected, just pass 0.

I think you should change the `-1` to `0` if you have 1 camera in your system.

Comment: VideoCapture cap(0) fails to find the default camera also. Passing -1, searches for all available cameras, hence its better than using 0.