# videocapture can't open default camera

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-12.04, webcam, video-capture

I tried to open default camera using below code. But it can't. There is a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749498/cant-access-webcam-with-opencv) same issue.But I can't find a menu to include HAVE_VIDEOINPUT HAVE_DSHOW. ( I tried cap(0) and cap(1) )

```
VideoCapture cap(1); // open the default camera
int iSliderValue1 = 50, iSliderValue2 = 255;
Mat thresholdImage;
Mat frame;


if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
{
    cout << "Webcam cannot open!\n" ;
    return -1;
}
```

Also,when I run "lsusb" command, the output is below
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `cap(-1)` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I installed xenomai on ubuntu and compiled kernel. Before it, my code was fine. Maybe default camera was changed. How can I check id of default camera?

Comment: Experimentation! Can you check that your camera works with other applications?

Comment: A camera is likely to show up as `/dev/videoX`, X being some number. That goes as the device ID in `cap.open(X)`.

Comment: @a-Jays when I run "ls /dev/video*", the output is "/dev/video*
ls: cannot access /dev/video*: No such file or directory".

Comment: on my pc,there is not video folder under dev/. Should I install cheese like below link?   http://shainky-at-ubuntu.blogspot.com.tr/2009/04/running-webcams-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue might be, since `lsusb` shows your camera. Install gucviewer and see if you can get your camera to work. Maybe some issue with the drivers?