# Unable to open my laptop camera using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and trying to capture video from my laptop camera using

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0
```

I am following the tutorial [capturing-images-videos](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html)

I tried  VideoCapture cap(0); with different parameters (0,1,2) but its not working for me. Also I have checked device manager my cam is working fine (also with skype, it working).
I am able to play video using other constructor of VideoCapture.
Iam using Windows 7 (64-bit) and my laptop is HP ProBook 4530s. Also I am using OpenCV OpenCV2.4.5
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749498/cant-access-webcam-with-opencv) seems similar, have you tried the solution proposed there?

Comment: Adrien's link seems like a good solution, otherwise try a different brand of webcam to see if the problem is in the camera or your software configuration.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio; can you please guide me how to recompile opencv_highgui and change the "Preprocesser Definitions". I am not familiar with CMake and I used only solution files for rebuilding the libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct, and I am able to create window to display image captured by camera. The problem was I was using Visual Studio in my VM now I am using it on Host OS (Windows 7).
Can anyone please mention if there is any problem in accessing Camera in VM?
thanks @Adrein and @diip for your time